# Split text into words

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, split

I have this HTML data

```html
<div id="sample">
    <p style="text-align: center;">
        <span style="font-family: 'comic sans ms', sans-serif; font-size: medium;">
            <strong>
                word1&nbsp;
                <span style="line-height: 1.5;">
                    word2&nbsp;
                </span>
                <span style="line-height: 1.5;">
                    word3&nbsp;
                </span>
                <span style="line-height: 1.5;">
                </span>
            </strong>
        </span>
    </p>
</div>
```

I want to get the text within the `div` element.

This is my JavaScript code:

```js
var text = document.getElementById('sample');
var text_content = jQuery(text).text();
console.debug(text_content);
```

The console logs `word1 word2 word3`.

I want it word by word, so I used the `split` method:

```js
var text_content_array = text_content.split(" ");
console.debug(text_content_array);
```

The console logs `["word1 word2 word3"]`. The string was not tokenized.

I tried this code with no luck:

```js
var text_content_array = text_content.split(" \n\r\t\b\f");
console.debug(text_content_array);
```

What shall I do to get an array of words out of the string?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eqk1e7rL/

Comment: your code works fine, the split returns an array of words. Check the above jsfiddle

Comment: @Bsienn: Your JSFiddle is very different from the OP's code. You use `text.innerText` instead of `jQuery(text).text()`, which gives a completely different result. and you have also used `text_content.trim().split(' ')` instead of `text_content.split(' ')`. But still your version shows `["alyssa ", "enganio ", "gono"]` with a space after the first two words

Comment: @Borodin I should have cleared more, I was in hurry. The above fiddle is not by me, But its a correct version. I'll explain. the `.text()` returns text PLUS spaces & new lines as they are in the code, indentation etc.. Thus doing split wont work on the string containing new lines nor will `trim()`. `.innerText` solves all those issue and returns clean text only. And then the magic `.split(' ')` and Voila. We are good to Go.

Comment: @Bsienn: Sure, I understand that. But you said ***"your code works fine, the split returns an array of words"*** while the OP's code ***doesn't*** "work fine", and the JSFiddle that you linked to is nothing like the OP's code

Answer (score 0):

You can use trim method and regex to get the array.

Something like that: `console.log(text_content.trim().split(/[\s,]+/))`

Here's jsbin [example](https://jsbin.com/getehunepo/1/edit?html,js,console,output) with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
var text = document.getElementById('sample');
        var text_content = jQuery(text).text();

        var text_content_array = new Array(); 
        text_content_array = text_content.split(" ");
        for (var i = 0; i < text_content_array.length; i++) {
            if (text_content_array[i].trim().length > 0)
                console.debug(text_content_array[i]);
        }
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var text_content_array = text_content.split(/&nbsp;|\b\s+/g);
```

Comment: This produces the result `["\n    \n        \n            \n                alyssa", "enganio", "gono", ""]`

Comment: This is solvable by adding the relative escapes in the RegEx. Anyway it's annoying receive downvote when you are trying to help a person

Comment: I am sure that it's equally annoying to receive misleading, untested and malfunctioning code when you're looking for help. Your suggestion is a *long* way from working, and you don't even appear to know what your regex pattern matches. Please show how you would fix your solution by adding the *relevant escapes*.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var a = $("#sample").text().trim();
var b = a.replace(/\s+/g,',');
var c = b.split(',')
alert(c);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sum1/xyp3cn37/1/

Comment: I wonder why you're converting all sequences of whitespace to commas and then splitting on commas? It has the same effect as just splitting on sequences of whitespace, without the intermediate variable

Comment: @Borodin all sequence of whitespace is not converted to commas but to a single comma :D, this way we have just a single comma seperating the actual text.

Comment: You can achieve the same thing with `var c = a.split(/\s+/)`

Comment: if you use this : var c = a.split(/\s+/), you'll get value of c as 'alyssaundefinedenganioundefinedgono'
Now its impossible to seperate the strings.

Comment: `split` returns an *array of strings*, and I can't understand how you could think it returned a single string like that. Where do the `undefined` substrings come from, and why has the array been collapsed into a single string?

Comment: @Borodin my mistake :D

Answer (score -2):

Newlines and the non-breaking space won't match the string `" "`, but they *will* match the regex pattern `\s`

The simplest way to gather all the separate words from your text is to use `match()` to find all sequences of non-space characters (`\S`). This method obviates the need to trim the string before splitting it. Like this

```
var text = document.getElementById('sample');
var text_content_array = jQuery(text).text().match(/\S+/g);
console.debug(text_content_array);
```

#### output

```
["word1", "word2", "word3"]
```